# C# Best Practice - What is the best practice when converting int? to int

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, repository, nullable

I have a nullable int coming in from the database from a stored procedure that I know will not have a null value. I have done the bellow:

```
    public List<EngineerDetails> GetCarouselEngineerDetailsList(int customerID)
    {
        using (var db = new MainEntities80())
        {
            var foo0= db.procedure().Select(s => new fooo()
            {
                foo= s.foo,
                foo2 = s.foo2,
                foo3 = s.foo3 ,
                foo4 = s.foo4 ,
                x = s.CurrentJobId.Value
            }).ToList();
            return foo0;
        }
    }
```

But I wanted to know although I know that the value will always be there. Is it good practice to check before getting the value. Maybe with a turnary expression.
Or because we know it will not be null should we forget about the check?

Comment: Why is it a nullable `int` at all if it can never be null?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: I can think of a number of reasons why it could make sense - for example, it may not be non-null for *all* rows, but if `s` is the result of a query, the non-null check may already have been performed there.

Comment: @Oliver: Your code doesn't make sense. Why do you still use a `int?` there instead of assigning the value to an `int` variable. Otherwise all the code  must still know that it's a nullable that can actually never be null.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I updated it to give you abit more context sorry for not making it clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `InvalidOperationException` will be thrown if `s.CurrentJobId` is actually null anyway. That's almost always the best outcome for situations of "the world is not the way I expect it to be" so it makes sense to use the code exactly as-is.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (s.CurrentJobID.HasValue)
{
    CurrentJobID = s.CurrentJobID.Value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
int result = s.CurrentJobId?? Int32.MinValue;
```

This will make sure that the value of x is assigned to result, but if s.CurrentJobId is null, Int32.MinValue will be assigned to it.

It will prevent an exception to be thrown, and you can verify afterwards if it was null anyway by checking on Int32.MinValue.

However, if the value should indeed never be null, it is a better option for an exception to be thrown and fail fast.

Answer (score -2):

You can use `CurrentJobID = s.CurrentJobID.GetValueOrDefault()`.

If NULL is encountered then this will produce the default value for the underlying type, which for numbers is always 0.

Or if you'd rather have an 'exceptional' value such as -1, then you can do so with `CurrentJobID = s.CurrentJobID.GetValueOrDefault(-1)`.

Comment: That's going to *silently* end up with a value of 0 when the world isn't as the OP expects it to be. The code will continue, quite possibly overwriting valid data with invalid data. It's like using `as` instead of a cast when the rest of the code has been written *expecting* the conversion to be valid. Embrace exceptions here - it's dangerous to continue as if all is well when actually you're in unexpected territory.